# Does these sequence and series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in C^1[-\pi,\pi]$ st $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$ and define $$a_n=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} f(t)\cos nt dt\,$$ for $n \in\Bbb{N}$ . Then does the sequence $\{na_n\}$ converges? And does the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n^2|a_n|^2$ converges as $n\to \infty$.

I know that $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and if the series converges the $\{na_n\}$ must converge to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By integration by parts, we have:
$$ n\, a_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\, n\cos(nt)\, dt = -\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f'(t)\sin(n t)\,dt \tag{1}$$
and since $f'\in C^0([-\pi,\pi])$, the RHS of $(1)$ converges to zero by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.
$f'\in C^0([-\pi,\pi])$ implies $f'\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$, hence
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} n^2 a_n^2 <+\infty $$
follows from [Bessel's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first question is answered by the celebrated [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Since the Fourier coefficients of $f'$ are $na_n$, by applying the Bessel inequality to $f'$ you get $\sum_n n^2 a_n^2 \leq \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f'|^2$.

Comment: I do not agree about the second part. $f'\in C^0([-\pi,\pi])$ implies $f'\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$, hence the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}n^2 a_n^2$ converges to something less or equal to the squared $L^2$-norm of $f'$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer.